# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, html, css, imagen, aplicación-web

Estoy intentando cargar un carrousel de bootstrap a mi pagina, me detecta el movimiento, pero no la letra ni las imagenes y me aparece el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi index solo tengo esto

```
<?php
include_once("admin/view/header.php");
include_once("admin/view/inicio.php");
include_once("admin/view/footer.php");
?>
```

Tambien me aparece la navbar pero no las imagenes

Este es mi codigo de inicio.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Dónde esta mi error o como lo soluciono?